# Data Extraction in Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-extraction

I have dataframe like:

```
Names        Subsets    Subnames       SubNumber       Numbers
AE,AI,AK     OP,OP,DO   ABC,ABC,ABC    A-890,A891      9OP-A,98-OPB,8IC,87AC,58AP,7PL
AO,AI        DO,AP      KLM,ABC        P890            L97, 52PL
IK,LJ,MI     OP,OP,DO   IJK,IJK,OPQ    90AKI           87AU, 90OP,89JN
```

From a dataframe like this,

For subsets with `OP,OP,DO` I need Numbers for Names ending with `I`.

for eg. As First row has subset `OP,OP,DO` and the name with first index has letter `I` at end. So Numbers with every first index `98-OPB,58AP` is the output I need. (Every first index means, there are three elements in Name. So after the second index in numbers, again zeroth index starts)

```
Names        Subsets    Subnames       SubNumber       Numbers                         Output
AE,AI,AK     OP,OP,DO   ABC,ABC,ABC    A-890,A891      9OP-A,98-OPB,8IC,87AC,58AP,7PL  98-OPB,58AP
AO,AI        DO,AP      KLM,ABC        P890            L97, 52PL
IK,LJ,MI     OP,OP,DO   IJK,IJK,OPQ    90AKI           87AU, 90OP,89JN                 89JN
```

In the third row, `MI` is second index, hence number with second index are needed `89JN` here.

Indexing starting from zero.

Comment: You say every second index, but that doesn't seem to be reflected in your examples: in `9OP-A,98-OPB,8IC,87AC,58AP,7PL`, the "number" `98-OPB` is at the first index, and then `58AP` is three indices after that. In `87AU, 90OP,89JN`, the "number" `89JN` is the third index.

Comment: Edited. Also index varies according the ```Names``` column where it ends qith ```I```.

Comment: What does "Numbers with every first index" even mean? It's not at all clear how you get `98-OPB, 58AP` from the first row.

Comment: I get those because ```98-OPB, 58AP``` mean that they have names that end with an ```I```. Every first index means, As there are three elements in Names. Those three are mapped in numbers, so after the second index, again zeroth index starts.

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially a `for` loop, because you are dealing with the `object dtype`. You might be able to make some minor improvements, but I don't really see how to make any big gains off the top of my head -- this is some pretty messy "extraction" logic:

```py
def extract(row):
    names = row.Names.split(",")
    numbers = row.Numbers.split(",")
    idxs = {i for i, name in enumerate(names) if name[-1] == "I"}
    return ",".join(num for i, num in enumerate(numbers) if i % len(names) in idxs)
```

Output:

```py
>>> df["Output"] = df[df["Subsets"] == "OP,OP,DO"].apply(extract, axis=1)
>>> df
      Names   Subsets     Subnames   SubNumber                         Numbers       Output
0  AE,AI,AK  OP,OP,DO  ABC,ABC,ABC  A-890,A891  9OP-A,98-OPB,8IC,87AC,58AP,7PL  98-OPB,58AP
1     AO,AI     DO,AP      KLM,ABC        P890                        L97,52PL          NaN
2  IK,LJ,MI  OP,OP,DO  IJK,IJK,OPQ       90AKI                  87AU,90OP,89JN         89JN
```

If you don't want the `NaN`:

```py
df["Output"] = df["Output"].fillna("")
```

Comment: ```df["Output"] = df[df["Subsets"] == "OP,OP,DO"].apply(extract, axis=1)``` for this line there's an error ```raise ValueError("Columns must be same length as key")```